Selection of Interpolation Center as Integer Optimization Problem
$\newcommand{\realset}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\laplaceop}{\mathcal{L}}$
$\newcommand{\ztransop}{\mathcal{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\sampop}[1]{\operatorname{S}_{#1}}$
$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$
$\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}$
$\newcommand{\intset}{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\posintset}{\mathbb{Z}^{+}}$
Interpolation can be described as follows: given a discrete function $s_{d}$ sampled from a continuous function $s_{c}$, how to evaluate $s_{c}\left(t\right)$ for an arbitrary $t \in \realset$ from $s_{d}$. We have the following theorem from Shannon's sampling theory (ignorance of which should not impact proof construction, and I do not wish to go into all details of the frequency domain to explain it):
Let $x_{c}$ be a continuous signal, $T \in \mathbb{R}$, which satisfies Shannon's sampling theorem with respect to $x_{c}$, $x_{d} = \sampop{T} x_{c}$. Then for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{equation*}
x_{c}\left(t\right) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x_{d}\left(n\right)\frac{\sin{\left(\pi\left(t - nT\right)/T\right)}}{\pi\left(t - nT\right)/T} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x_{d}\left(n\right) \frac{\sin{\left(\pi\left(t/T - n\right)\right)}}{\pi \left(t / T - n\right)}.
\end{equation*}
In particular, $\sampop{T}$ stands for sampling operator using an interval $T$.
In practice, a truncation number is used to make the summation realizable in an algorithm. An interesting question then, is, given a truncation number $M$, how to determine the best central point for interpolation such that the interpolation is best for an arbitrary $t$. An engineering practice is to use the integer nears to $t/T$ as the interpolation center. Intuitively, this selection makes sense, as you definitely want to use the point nearest to the evaluation point as the interpolation center. To mathematically answer this question, I would like to come up with a proof for the following theorem:
Let $x_{c}$ be a continuous signal, $t \in \realset$, $T \in \mathbb{R}$, which satisfies Shannon's sampling theorem with respect to $x_{c}$ (which simply means that the above reconstruction theorem can be used), $x_{d} = \sampop{T} x_{c}$. Also, let
\begin{equation*}
n_{0} = \argmin_{n \in \intset} \abs{t / T - n}.
\end{equation*}
$M \in \posintset$ and $f$ be a function such that for any $m \in \intset$,
\begin{equation*}
f\left(m\right) = \sum_{n=-M}^{M} x_{d}\left(m - n\right)\frac{\sin\left(\pi\left(t / T - m + n\right)\right)}{\pi\left(t / T - m + n\right)}
\end{equation*}
and let $g$ be a function such that for any $k \in \intset$,
\begin{equation*}
g\left(k\right) = \abs{x_{c}\left(t\right) - f\left(k\right)}.
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
\argmin_{k \in \intset} g\left(k\right) = n_{0}.
\end{equation*}
